# Most efficient JavaScript for sending to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb, analytics

I'm working on an analytics solution that stores data in a MongoDB. Currently I have a javascript which uses an XMLHTTPRequest object to send data to a PHP file using the GET method.

The PHP in turn then creates/updates a document on the MongoDB.

Is this an efficient way of doing things? Is there a better way to do it?

Whilst it's just a side project at the moment I want to try and make this a scalable solution from the outset.

Comment: OK thanks for the replies. Perhaps I should rephrase the questions as naively I wasn't aware of the exact limitations due to cross domain policies. In that case, what is the best way to send values using javascript on one domain to my PHP/MongoDB on another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, there's a reason to use POST because of browsers' limitations. But I'd like to make another agruement.

POST makes more sense in terms of HTTP method definitions. GET is supposed to be safe and make no changes to your system state (database). This is typically enforced in services, but not as much in HTML form processing.

> Some methods (for example, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS and TRACE) are defined as safe, which means they are intended only for information retrieval and should not change the state of the server. In other words, they should not have side effects, beyond relatively harmless effects such as logging, caching, the serving of banner advertisements or incrementing a web counter. Making arbitrary GET requests without regard to the context of the application's state should therefore be considered safe.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods)

Additional reading:

[HTTP Spec - Method Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Answer (score 1):

A GET is limited in size for the browser, while a POST is not.

And it doesn't change that much in the PHP side.

Answer (score 1):

For what it sounds like you are doing, your implementation should be fine. However IMHO, I would probably change the XHR from get to post simply to prevent problems with sending long data. Although servers should be able to handle URLs (including the query string) of any length, browsers generally only support up to about 2k characters. Anything over that and you would have problems. POST doesn't have this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

What you propose should be fine.

If you are going to use the javascript on other sites (While keeping your php on a single domain), you are going to run into issues with cross domain policies.

Comment: You can make GET calls to other domains by inserting an image for instance. You can't read the response, but the call hits the server. That's how the analytics trackers work.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You can pass data back by including a javascript file. its a little bit more difficult but it can be done. Ajax calls are directly affected by cross domain policies.